# Finding limit including binomial coefficients

Tags: calculus, limits

I recently came across a question from my calculus problem book and encountered a pretty good looking problem.

It goes as

Find $$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[1/n]\frac{3n\choose n}{2n\choose n}$$

I tried expanding the binomial terms with no clue as to what to do next.I tried to make use of the squeeze theorem but couldn't find the apt assumptions.

Any help to solve this problem would be appreciated.(including motivation for the solution)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show what you tried? Also, do you mean $n\to\infty$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:- There are many ways to solve this .

Are you familiar with [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#:%7E:text=Stirling%27s%20formula%20for%20the%20gamma%20function,-For%20all%20positive&text=large%20enough%20in%20absolute%20value,of%20Stirling%27s%20series%20above%20for&text=is%20replaced%20with%20z%20%E2%88%92%201.)?

Or do you know that if $\{x_{n}\}$ is a sequence such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n}}$ exists then $\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_{n})^{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n}}$  . The second one is what is often called Cauchy's Second Limit Theorem .

Try them out

Comment: Sorry no...i am a highschool student and this is a problem of my highschool problem book

Comment: Well, in any case, I gave you something to work with didn't I as you asked for "motivation"?. Try and use the fact that $n!\sim (\frac{n}{e})^{n}\sqrt{2\pi n}$ and see what you get.

Comment: I appreciate your help providing the much needed motivation...by any chance are you aware of any method which uses rather simpler results...as the book i use is designed for high school students...i feel the method you suggest would be somewhat an overkill.

Comment: @Mathenthusiast It would be helpful for you to state what you know. EG Have you dealt with $\lim {2n \choose n}^ {1/n}$? What chapter is the problem from? What book are you using?   $\quad$ Gandalf's approach via "Cauchy's Second Limit theorem" gives a direct calculation. Are you saying that you're not familiar with the theorem?

Comment: @Mathenthusiast I myself encourage people to try problems using the methods they know of so I do get your point. But still , if the problem is hard enough for your level, then there is no guilt in seeking more powerful results. In any case, I think most math enthusiasts at high school level are familar with Stirling's approximation and it is a VERY VERY helpful thing to know and you will be using it again and again even at highest research levels in analysis or probability. So , personally I would not see any fault if my student used stirling's approximation to solve this problem.